# Crystal Report- record number reset

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I create a crystal report and has field called row-counter. I wrote formula for increase counter id.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar x=1;
x:=x+1;
x
```

but i want reset(row counter number is 1) counter id when new page or after certain value.How should I change this formula?

Comment: Create a another formula to reset the record number WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar x:=0; and place it in page header

Comment: thanks Mahendra.It works